# How do i make fluid movement with arrows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, canvas

I am trying to make a game with where you can control a box with the arrow-keys but i am stuck. I have used this code before and it worked but now i det a error and i dont know how to fix it.

When this code works the player will lagg a lot and i want to make a fluid charactermovement how do i do that?

I would be very grateful if someone could hjempe me with both problems

the code i have so far is

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var farge = ["blue", "darkorchid", "yellowgreen", "violet", "peru", "darkorange", "lightskyblue"];
var tileldig = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);

var kuler = [
    {r: 10, x: canvas.width/2, y: canvas.height-100, f: "red"},
    //{r: 50, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 3, f: "green"},
]
var fiender = [
    {r: 5, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 3, },
]



function bounceCircle () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) {
        kuler[i].x += 0;
        kuler[i].y += 0;


        ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        function tast (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                kuler[i].x -= 10;
            };
            if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                kuler[i].x += 10;
            };
            if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                kuler[i].y -= 10;
            };
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                kuler[i].y += 10;
            };

        }
        document.onkeydown = tast;

    };



    for (var i = 0; i < fiender.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(fiender[i].x, fiender[i].y, fiender[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        fiender[i].y += fiender[i].vy;

        if (fiender.y >= canvas.height) {
            circles.splice(i,1)
        };
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(bounceCircle);
}

setInterval(function(){
    fiender.push({r: 5, x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1), y: 0, vx:0 , vy: 3, f: "green"});
}, 800);



bounceCircle();
```

to see demo of what i have so far click the link [**DEMO**](http://elevweb.akershus-fk.no/~stmo0403/it2/spill/)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tast() in your version can be called whenever the player presses a key. At that time, the variable i within that function doesn't appear to point to your for loop variable. Execution might not be within that loop at the time tast() is called. You're also redefining the function with every call to bounceCircle(). Probably not good for performance, and not clearly necessary. A switch also makes more sense than the if statements currently used for key presses.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    farge = ["blue", "darkorchid", "yellowgreen", "violet", "peru", "darkorange",       
             "lightskyblue"],
    tileldig = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);

var kuler = [
      {r: 10, x: canvas.width/2, y: canvas.height-100, f: "red"},
      //{r: 50, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 3, f: "green"},
    ];
var fiender = [
      {r: 5, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 3, },
    ];

document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {            
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      kuler[0].x -= 10;
      break;
    case 39:
      kuler[0].x += 10;
      break;
    case 38:
      kuler[0].y -= 10;
      break;
    case 40:
      kuler[0].y += 10;
      break;
  }
};  

function bounceCircle () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) {
        kuler[i].x += 0;
        kuler[i].y += 0;

        ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();             
    }



    for (var i = 0; i < fiender.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(fiender[i].x, fiender[i].y, fiender[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        fiender[i].y += fiender[i].vy;

        if (fiender.y >= canvas.height) {
          circles.splice(i,1)
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(bounceCircle);
}

setInterval(function(){
    fiender.push({r: 5, x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1), y: 0, vx:0 ,
                  vy: 3, f: "green"});
}, 800);



bounceCircle();
```

This works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5pb8ov8/1/)), although it no longer loops through multiple "kuler"s. It's not clear to me why you need more than one given the example, but this should get you moving in the right direction.